# Temporal extensions to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, temporal-database

Anyone know of any temporal (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database) extensions to SQL Server?

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/557002/sql-temporal

Comment: Sure wish there was some traction on this! Looks like MS is still sitting on their hands letting IBM DB2 and Oracle race to the front with these features. :-/  https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/816474/include-features-to-support-temporal-databases-as-introduced-by-sql-2011

Comment: I feel like you could get something interesting working with CLR user-defined types, although performance would be a challenge. If I'm sufficiently motivated, and you're still interested I'll knock something up and github it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but the usual solution in SQL Server is to create a "Date Dimension" database that you can join in your query. A DateDim is basically just a list of dates, but it includes columns like fiscal quarter and calendar quarter number, first/last day of that month, etc.: stuff that's difficult or time consuming to calculate on the fly but is easy to pull from a joined table.

If you search "sql date dimension" you'll find some code that will generate the table for you, though you'll need to tweak it to fit your needs. They tend to run day-by-day, but if you need hourly tracking you'll need to alter the code accordingly, for example.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2016 introduced Temporal Database capabilities.

See:

- [The MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935015(v=sql.130).aspx)
- [This Channel 9 Video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Data-Exposed/Temporal-in-SQL-Server-2016)
- [The public preview (CTP2) announcment](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2015/05/27/sql-server-2016-first-public-preview-now-available.aspx)